# How to unblock a file from a htaccess blocked folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a sitemap like this:

```
   -js
   -php
   -css
   -user
       -user1
           -files  //folder i want to remain blocked
           -index.php //main file i want to unblock
       -user2
           -files  //folder i want to remain blocked
           -index.php //main file i want to unblock
       -user3
       .
       .
```

the user1,user2 are dynamically created folders according to users.
how to do this with a central htaccess file??

Comment: google search [htaccess block all but one file](https://www.google.com.au/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=htaccess+block+all+but+one+file) and choose the first link. and why upvote a question where it is obvious that the OP has done zero research